# Restrict search and replace to a highlighted portion of text. (Overleaf)

Tags: overleaf

It often happens that I would like to use the "replace all" function on a specific part of the document. For example a matrix in which many entries have an "a" that would like to replace by a "b^2" without this happening over my entire document.
Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: welcome and please see the answer below for your requirement  -you can see that within the selected code all `a` have been changed to `aaa`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

select code to search / replace

press ctrl+F

dropdown box will appear as shown in image below

select search within selection-- marked with red arrow

enter in first row of dropdown the item to search

in second row type in the new word or text to replace with -- here you see `aaa`

click replace all

Comment: Brilliant thanks very much !